# CoreDataBooks Example - Start Cells at Index 1?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Im working with the CoreDataBooks example project from Apple and I want to have a custom cell at indexPath 0 in my tableview and then have my core data fetched results start from index 1.

I have tried some different solutions but can't get it working, if you have any ideas it would due appreciated thanks.

If you want to know what I have tried and failed let me know. What I want to achieve seems simple, just start the fetched results at cell 1 rather than 0.

Edit 2:

All my UITableViewDataSource and configureGuestCell code:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {    
        if (indexPath.row == 0) 
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"statsCell";

            GuestStatsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                cell = [[GuestStatsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }

            //Configure the cell.
            [self configureStatsCell:cell];

            return cell;
        }
        if (indexPath.row > 0)
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"guestCell";

            customGuestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                cell = [[customGuestCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }

            // Configure the cell.
            [self configureGuestCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

            return cell;
        }
    }


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int cellHeight;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        cellHeight = 240;
    }
    else
    {
        cellHeight = 44;
    }

    return cellHeight;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (void)configureGuestCell:(customGuestCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    //Configure the cell to show the Guests first and last name and other details
    GuestInfo *guest = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.guestNameLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", guest.firstName, guest.lastName];

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {

        // Delete the managed object.
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) 
        {
            // Update to handle the error appropriately.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            exit(-1);  // Fail
        }
    }   
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Create and push a detail view controller.
    guestListDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[guestListDetailViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    GuestInfo *selectedGuest = (GuestInfo *)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Pass the selected book to the new view controller.
    detailViewController.guest = selectedGuest;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please post all UITableViewDataSource and configureGuestCell code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects] +1;
}

- (void)configureGuestCell:(customGuestCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row - 1) inSection:indexPath.section]
    //Configure the cell to show the Guests first and last name and other details
    GuestInfo *guest = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];

    cell.guestNameLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", guest.firstName, guest.lastName];

}
```

Small explanation:
you should return a one row more in numberOfRowsInSection, but, to prevent errors, row number should be decremented before calling [NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath].

Comment: Works really well thanks. Any reason why this is a decrement in row though and not an increment? As an example surely you are moving the fetched result from index 0 to index 1 and so forth, not the other way?

Comment: It's simple, indexPath in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  has a range from 0 to 'numberOfRowsInSection'.
We add one row in numberOfRowsInSection, and now range increase, but in fetchedResultsController we still have one object less. So we have to decrease indexPath (row number) for every row after first, where is added cell.

Comment: An interesting thing to note. I have done as you recommended and upon deleting a fetched result from the table, if its the last one, it remove the custom cell at index 0 with it. Then upon adding a record (if none exist) the summary will reappear. Any ideas why?

Comment: Of course whenever you have '[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]]' you should replace it as in 'configureGuestCell'.

Comment: I have been doing so where appropriate testing with every change I'm not having any luck. Sorry to ask for more of your help. It appears that my custom cell (which is actually at index 0) and the first core data record (at index 1) thinks it is at index 0, resulting probably in why my custom cell disappears with the core data record and when I change any information in that specific core data record it crashes expecting a statsCell rather than a guestCell (as it thinks its index 0). Is your solutions, used in the right way, the only thing I need? I can't fix the said problems.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand your message. Could you explain what happened? As I wrote before, NSFetchedResultsController has objects  numerated from 0 to indexCount -1. If you add some objects on start of your tableView, you always should deduct this objects from index.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6782/discussion-between-josh-kahane-and-tomasz-wojtkowiak)

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 to the indexPath.row value....?!

Comment: Check my edit. I have attempted having the core data cells only be used on cells beyond 0 and not including. Then cell 0 is my custom cell. This results in cell 0 being my custom cell, but also when selected goes to the first core data record.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you also need to edit the `-tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:` to return (realRows + 1) as well.

Likewise you will want to **decrement** the row by one whenever you are referencing your `NSFetchedResultsController` | `NSArray` which I suspect is in your `configureCell:atIndexPath:`

Anywhere you want/need to touch the data source you will need to adjust for that row either by incrementing or decrementing.

### Response to OP

Don't change the `NSIndexPath`, there is no need.  Adjust the index in your `-configureCell: atIndexPath:` or anywhere else that touches that index value:

```
-(void)configureCell:(id)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
  NSInteger finalIndex = [indexPath row] - 1;
  NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:finalIndex inSection:[indexPath section]];
  id object = [[self myNSFRC] objectAtIndexPath:newPath];
  //Continue configuring your cell
}
```

Obviously if you are using an array then don't bother creating a new `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: It makes sense, the first thing I tried was `return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects] + 1;` in my `numberOfRowsInSection` method, but it just throws up a index beyond bounds error and crashes the app when the table loads. But for the other bit your recommending instead of passing just `indexPath`, perhaps `indexPath + 1`? How would I do that, as obviously that exactly doesn't work.